# Expect: Same pattern, different answer

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to automate the answers on a menu-like script to Start/Stop a propietary service.

At first, the menu asks which type of service are you trying to affect *(press 1)*. Then, asks you for the action to perform *(press 2 to stop)*. Then, performs the action and tells you to press any key to continue, which takes you back to the "action" menu, where you have to press 0 to go back to the first menu, then 0 again to quit.

The thing is, if I just ignore the steps after the service is stopped, next time I enter the menu script, it skips the first part and goes straight to the "action" menu (It saves the option you selected on the first menu somewhere, but I don't know where).

Is there any way to tell expect to `send "0"` the second time it sees the "action" menu?

This is the script I have right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set startstop [lindex $argv 0]

if {$startstop == "start"} {
  set sendnumber "1"
} elseif {$startstop == "stop"} {
  set sendnumber "2"
} else {
  exit 0
}

log_user 0
spawn ./menuscript.sh
expect {
  "first menu" {
    send "1"
    exp_continue
  }
  "action menu" {
    send "$sendnumber"
    exp_continue
  }
  "Press any key to continue" {
    send "\r"
    exit 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can provide only a rough hint because `expect` is for me new too. According to [Wikipedia: Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is an extension of [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl). In this case, you have a rich script language "built-in". Thus, it should be possible to manage some state (in variables) and to involve conditions to decide what to `send` when.

Comment: Reading your sample again, I realized you already used variables and the `if` statement. Why not doing it similar in the `"action menu"` branch?

Comment: how do you tell if it's *the second time* you see *the "action" menu*?

Comment: That's the thing. How do you say "Do this if it's the first time you see this menu, and do that if it's the second time you see it". Maybe with a variable that "counts" the occurrence of some word/regex?